# Qt C++ XML Unexpected Character

Tags: c++, xml, qt

I've been trying to iterate through an xml file, but before doing so I have written this line of code:

```
if(!dom.setContent(&file, &error, &line, &column)) {
     qDebug() << "Error:" << error << "in line " << line << "column" << column;
}
```

For some reason it keeps returning

```
Error: "unexpected character" in line  2 column 2
```

This is my xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ItemRow name="{0405d28e-fa16-443d-b70e-ba62efb60973}" website="test" login="test1" password="test2" category="No Category"/>
<(line 2 column 2 here)ItemRow name="{69407bfb-ecbd-4456-abfb-08c19f5c4b19}" website="test3" login="test4" password="test5" category="No Category"/>
```

I have been trying to fix this for hours and have made no progress, any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In cases like this, you can try the w3 XML validator: http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input and see what happens.

I pasted the code (without the error message):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ItemRow name="{0405d28e-fa16-443d-b70e-ba62efb60973}" website="test" login="test1" password="test2" category="No Category"/>
<ItemRow name="{69407bfb-ecbd-4456-abfb-08c19f5c4b19}" website="test3" login="test4" password="test5" category="No Category"/>
```

and got the message

> Line 3, Column 126: document type does not allow element "ItemRow" here

I think you are simply missing the root element of the XML structure.
The following XML is valid:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <ItemRow name="{0405d28e-fa16-443d-b70e-ba62efb60973}" website="test" login="test1" password="test2" category="No Category"/>
    <ItemRow name="{69407bfb-ecbd-4456-abfb-08c19f5c4b19}" website="test3" login="test4" password="test5" category="No Category"/>
</root>
```

For reference: http://www.w3schools.com/XML/xml_tree.asp